# Правильное использование сокетов

Tags: c++, сокет

Как мне через сокет изменять переменные у всех пользователей?
Например, есть переменная `int a, b;`. Я хочу изменить ее у всех пользователей на произвольную. Будет ли правильным, если я помещу их в строку, а на стороне других пользователей ее правильно обработать? Например,

```
int a, b;
string vars = "Vars: a = 2, b = 1";
send(con, (const char*)vars.c_str(), (int)vars.size(), NULL);
```

а после уже обработать и задать значение

Comment: В принципе, да (только пользователи должны хотеть этого, сами должны читать сообщения и сами менять у себя переменные)

Comment: @avp Я бы хотел, чтобы при изменении значения у одного пользователя, они менялись у всех. Аля id ключа и значение. То есть, сам принцип правильный?

Comment: Ну, вы должны при изменении и одного послать от него broadcast udp datagram всем. Они одолжны это сообщение сами прочесть и изменить свои переменные. Автоматически (без программирования у всех такого протокола) ничего не будет. Конечно, вместо broadcast можно использовать сервер. Все регистрируются на нем и шлют ему сообщения об изменениях. Он рассылает все остальным